# Nginx downloads PHP instead of executing it

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, nginx-location

I want to make certain php files accessible via http only.

So I added location = /example.php{} as shown in the code below.

```
server {
listen 80;
ssl off;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /var/www/example;

location ~* \.(php)$ {
    # dostufdd
}

location = /example.php {
    #do stuff
}


location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

}

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example;
    index index.php;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/example.com.dhparam;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;


    # Set caches, protocols, and accepted ciphers. This config will
    # merit an A+ SSL Labs score.
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kED$

    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log warn;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    # Allow Lets Encrypt Domain Validation Program
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block dot file (.htaccess .htpasswd .svn .git .env and so on.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # Block (log file, binary, certificate, shell script, sql dump file) access.
    location ~* \.(log|binary|pem|enc|crt|conf|cnf|sql|sh|key)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

   location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

   location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpe?g|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
        expires max;
    }


    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }


    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


}
```

However, if I try to access to http://example.com/example.php, the php file is 
downloaded instead of executing.

but If i access https://example.com/example.php, it will be accessed normally.

I have no idea what to do.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx - Downloading PHP instead of executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819813/nginx-downloading-php-instead-of-executing)

Comment: Please explain what are the rules in "#do stuff". Otherwise looks like you forgot "fastcgi_pass" rules like in the duplicated question mentioned by @hassan.