# Download php file instead of executing with nginx and docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm using docker

and This my Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    php \
    php-fpm \
    nano
```

so as you see, we use nginx's latest version image and then run some of these bash command which you can see.

base on these configuration I'm trying to execute a php file to show **phpinfo()**

so I create a file in **/usr/share/nginx/html** called **index.php**

and when I try to use **index.php** like this **http://localhost:8000/index.php**, the php file start downloading immediately.

What should I do?

I know that this is a possible duplicate but I've tried something like this link:
[Nginx - Downloading PHP instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819813/nginx-downloading-php-instead-of-executing)

but nothing well happened.

Comment: You should almost always create a separate container to run php-fpm.  You also need to configure nginx to forward requests to the PHP container; it won't run the scripts on its own.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your reply, Why is it important to have 2 different containers?

Comment: @DavidMaze so Is it a important reason? I mean, we all use nginx and php-fpm all in one system without docker, so Why should we use them in seprate inside docker?

Comment: Typically a container is a wrapper around some single _process_; running multiple processes in a single container adds a fair bit of complication and adds questions around container lifecycle.  (If the PHP process outright crashes, should it take the nginx proxy with it?  What if a database is involved?)

Comment: @DavidMaze it still occurs this problem while I divided them to 2 different containers.

Comment: Can you add your nginx configuration to the question?  How are you launching the container?